# How to do a conditional chart in excel?

Tags: excel, charts

I have two columns 'age' and 'assistance' and I'd like to have a line chart that given the ages in the X-axis, it shows how many of them have assisted (assistance == true) in the Y-axis.

e.g -> There are three 29yo assistants

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to add the conditional part to just get columns with assistance as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below picture, I added a helper column "C", and then created a pivot table/chart from the table data.

The helper formula in C7 is =IF(B7,1,0)

This converts the TRUE to a number 1, allowing you to sum the age in a pivot table / chart.

Image of my setup > [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC6w9.png)